# How to modify the ExtractedEditText for a custom keyboard in Android

Tags: android, android-input-method, android-extracted-text

I want to change the font and text size of the text in a custom keyboard's extracted text view. How do I get a reference to the `EditText`?

I just learned how to do this by examining the `InputMethodService` source code, so I am posting this as a Q&A. My answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a reference to the `ExtractedEditText` by overriding `onCreateExtractTextView()` in your `InputMethodService` subclass. You can modify it there however you like before passing it on.

```
@Override
public View onCreateExtractTextView() {
    View extractedView = super.onCreateExtractTextView();
    ExtractEditText editText = extractedView.findViewById(android.R.id.inputExtractEditText);
    editText.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
    editText.setTextSize(myTextSize);
    return extractedView;
}
```

Note that the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService#onCreateExtractTextView()) says:

> `public View onCreateExtractTextView ()`
>
> Called by the framework to create the layout for showing extacted (sic)
>   text. Only called when in fullscreen mode. The returned view hierarchy
>   must have an [`ExtractEditText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/ExtractEditText) whose ID is [`R.id.inputExtractEditText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id#inputExtractEditText).