# Android Extracted Text UI: Customizing context menu items

Tags: android, android-extracted-text

I have an `EditText` with a custom `ActionModeCallback` to display additional context menu items via `setCustom[Insertion/Selection]ActionModeCallback`.

If the field is selected, and the screen is rotated, some keyboards display an *Extracted Text UI*, which no longer has the custom menu items.

Is there a means for me to either take control of the context menu items in the *Extracted Text UI*, or provide these items to the UI?

I'd prefer not to disable the *Extracted Text UI* if possible.

It seems that I can do this via a subclass of `InputMethodService`: [How to modify the ExtractedEditText for a custom keyboard in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997709/how-to-modify-the-extractededittext-for-a-custom-keyboard-in-android/50997710#50997710). But this appears to define a system-wide IME, which isn't ideal.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Refs:

- [What's the Android "Extracted Text UI"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906053/whats-the-android-extracted-text-ui)
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/ExtractEditText.html

Thanks in advance,